# input remembered without using a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, caching, onclick

If I use a form and submit button then the browser can remember the text input fields, but if I use only input types, no form and have the button action an onclick event, then the browser does not cache input values for the user.

Is there a way to have the browser still cache "form" inputs without using an actual submit?

below is sample code, showing my page.  When the user clicks search, then a javascript function is called that will populate the div "results".  Everything works except no browser will cache the text input.

```
<h2>Device Cleaner</h2>
<p>Enter MAC Address of device to clean:</p>
<input type="text" id="entry" name="macaddr" onkeypress="keyChecker(event)">
<button type="button" id="start" onclick="query()">Search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to force a browser to save this information. As long as the input you would like saved is relatively short, you could use JavaScript to store cookies with this information. Then when viewing the page in the future, you can use those cookies to fill the input fields. Be wary of sensitive information though.

Alternatively, you could store the user input on your own server through AJAX requests.

Comment: One caveat: Security recommendation is that in general, you should not save any sensitive information like passwords or social security numbers in localStorage/cookies/anything. This means for many forms of this type, the password field is the only one not-remembered.

Comment: Since I only had one field to cache, I went with this route. Security isn't much concern, as in my case this is an internal web page, not accessible outside my building.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the browser still cache "form" inputs without using an actual submit?

No.

What used to work in the past is submitting to an empty page, but that doesn't work anymore in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to update the "results" div using an asynchronous request in javascript, so that the page doesn't actually refresh/submit, but the results are simply displayed directly?

This would involve intercepting the submit action of the form, and writing a different endpoint on your server that would do the search, and *just* return the data your form needs. It's a bit much for me to describe in my answer, but it's something people commonly do for better usability; you'd find a better tutorial than I could provide by googling for "ajax form submit".

Comment: I tried this, and it works quite well in Firefox, but not chrome or IE.

Comment: There is no particular reason this shouldn't work in all browsers. You may want to open up some Javascript debugging tools to figure out exactly what's going wrong somewhere. (For the most recent versions of either browser, just press F12 to open a debugger)

Comment: To be clear, the form data is sent, and an answer is retrieved and displayed.  **BUT** only firefox caches the form data.  There were no javascript errors on the other browsers.

Comment: If the browser is doing a "page change" as if you entered a new URL (complete with a quick white-page view), then it's not being set up as I described it. AJAX wouldn't clear the form values or change the page's state in any way. Even things like the scroll position of the page won't change at all from an AJAX submit. Example: This comment box uses AJAX, and you notice the page doesn't do a complete refresh each time you submit one.