# Make browsers remember input fields without submitting (or having at all) a form?

Tags: ajax, forms, browser

I have a web application based on bootstrap (so, using jquery), and I'm trying to convert a classic html form-based search form to an ajax search form (to avoid page reload).

In the classic form-based, the button sends the html form as post, and the action page returns a table of results below the same form.

something like:

```
 <form action="/search" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchterms">
    <button type="button" onclick="submit();">Search!</button>
 </form>
```

In the ajax version, there is no form, but just a text field and the button calls a dosearch() function which makes an ajax request to a back end script which return search results, which are then used in a target DIV, showing a table of results, below the search input+button.

```
<input type="text" name="searchterms">
<button type="button" onclick="dosearch();">Search!</button>
```

Both work fine, but the second way avoid the browser to "collect" previously used search terms - I guess because there's no "submit".
My users like this "previous search terms" suggestion, and I would like to add it back, if possible, in the search "ajax" form.

I also tried to create an html form anyway, which encloses the input and the button, adding this event to its tag:

```
onSubmit='dosearch();return false;'
```

(if I don't return false, the form is submitted and action page loaded), like:

```
<form onsubmit='dosearch();return false;'>
    <input type="text" name="searchterms">
    <button type="button" onclick="dosearch();">Search!</button>
</form>
```

but even this seems not to work: new search terms are not "remembered" and suggested typing in the field...

I thought maybe my dosearch() function could add (most recent) search terms into a session/cookie but then I would need to read those stored values and create, each time, a sort of "dropdown" list for the input field, just as browsers usually do automatically... it should be not complicated but probably overkill...

Is there any way to make browsers "remember" inserted values even without submit? If not, what workaround is best/easiest?

edit: I've just found this

[input remembered without using a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240161/input-remembered-without-using-a-form)

but maybe after 5 years something changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to change the "button" type, to a "submit", and in this way *it seems* to work... page is not reloaded, ajax fills the results div and my new terms are remembered...

like:

```
<form onsubmit='dosearch();return false;'>
    <input type="text" name="searchterms">
    <button type="submit" >Search!</button>
</form>
```

it seems that if the "submit" is triggered through a "submit" button (even if it return false) the browsers stores input field values...

Answer (score 0):

you need to do with ajax

```
<form onsubmit='dosearch();return false;'>
<input type="text" name="searchterms" id="searchTerm">
<button type="button" onclick="dosearch();">Search!</button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosearch(){
val = $("#searchTerm").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "LoadProduct.php?val ="+val,
        type: "GET",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        }).done(function(respond){
            $("#LoadProductTd"+no).html(respond);
            $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); 
    });
}
</script>
```

so you can create LoadProduct.php file and in file you will get your search term n $_GET['val']

so you can use this for your query