# autocomplete on a form that does not submit

Tags: javascript, html

This must be done in pure js (no jquery).

I have the following form :

```
<!-- messenger -->
<form id="messenger_form" action="?">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0 pt-5">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text">Messenger</span>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="on" class="form-control" id="messenger" name="messenger" placeholder="setLedBrightness:64, sendToApi:foo=bar&baz=qux, rf@to:cmd">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is the js :

```
    var messenger_el = document.getElementById("messenger");
    var messenger_form = document.getElementById("messenger_form");

    // ...

    messenger_form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      socket.send(messenger_el.value);
      messenger_el.value = "";
    });
```

When I type "hello" inside the input named `messenger`, this basically sends "hello" via WebSocket (WITHOUT refreshing the page) and frees the input.

This is what I need : I want the input to hold the "hello" command into memory, aka browser's autocomplete. I noticed autocompletion only works when I remove the `e.preventDefault();`, which sadly then refreshes the page.

Question: How can I enforce autocomplete="on" on this input?

Comment: Your code empties out the `<input>` field explicitly. Perhaps you could not do that.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128385/make-browsers-remember-input-fields-without-submitting-or-having-at-all-a-form you should add a submit button (could be hidden)

Comment: @Pointy I need that field to be emptied.

Comment: @ITgoldman That solved it indeed. ```<input type="submit" style="display:none;">```